# How to decrypt data for an MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime, and writing encrypted data to my database using a function.

```
public string Encrypt(string encryptMe)
{
    return Helpers.Encryptor.Encrypt(encryptMe); 
}
```

On return the data is displayed like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
```

I want to decrypt the data before displaying it here using the following function:

```
public static string Decrypt(string decryptMe)
{
    return Helpers.Encryptor.Decrypt(decryptMe); ;
}
```

How can I decrypt my data?

Comment: Why can't you decrypt the model's properties in the controller before you return the view?

Comment: How would I do that David?

Comment: I tried this: public string d_Name{get{return Decrypt(_name);},set{  _name = Decrypt(value);}}, and then looking for model.d_Name in the View screen. That caused a Database error as it probably expected to find this value in the database - The model backing the 'BookingDBContext' context has changed since the database was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Property in the model called for example "DecryptedPhone".

This will only have a Get and will call the decrypting function:

```
public string DecryptedPhone
{
      get
      {
      return Decrypt(Phone);
      }
}

private string Phone;
```

The phone will be private so that it cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller's method, before the `return View(model);` line, you can decrypt the properties.  It would be something like this:

```
foreach (var item in model)
{
    item.Phone = Decrypt(item.Phone);
    item.Name = Decrypt(item.Name);
}

return View(model);
```

Comment: Won't that change the original values, David?

Comment: This changes the values in your model.  You can then use the regular editing fields to allow users to edit the values.  Then before you save them back to the database, you encrypt them again.